# PHP Verify Script

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

I have setup a system whereby a user recieves an email to which they click a button and it will verify their email address. It passes the following url variables to the page:

```
verify.php?email=testemail@gmail.com&first_name=Test&last_name=User
```

When the page loads, the information is passed to the database and store, however I have a error message appear afterwards? What am I doing wrong?

PHP Script (verify.php)

```
<?php
include("admin/dbh.php");

$email = $_GET['email'];
$first_name = $_GET['first_name'];
$last_name = $_GET['last_name'];
$today = date("Y/m/d");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM subscribersList WHERE email=$email LIMIT 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result -> num_rows){
    echo "<h1>This email address is already signed up to our mailing list!</h1>";
}else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO subscribersList (first_name, last_name, email, verified, subDate) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', 1, '$today')";
    $result = $conn -> query($sql);
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: What error message?

Comment: @JenR we should guess!!! Isn't it?

Comment: `email=$email` btw requires quotes.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @u_mulder This fixed everything. Thank you for the help :(